# Get icons from manifest file of process

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

I'm developing something like TaskManager. So I've all running applications/their processes. Now I need to obtain icons. For Metro UI app this is not so easier.
BUT they should store icons on manifest file.

Could you please give me any ideas how I can get manifest file from Metro UI application?